# Regex for Azure blob containers

Tags: c#, regex, azure

Trying to create a regex to use in the following code to ensure my input conforms to Azure blob container rules, but needing a regex means I have 2 problems.

Rules:

- Letters and numbers and hyphens only
- No spaces
- Must start with a letter or number

Not worried about lower case as I am going to .ToLower() it after this.

Tried this but it keeps $ and ^ so I must be doing something wrong?

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
        Regex regEx = new Regex("^[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9]|(\\-(?!\\-))){1,61}[a-z0-9]$|^\\$root$");
        var isContainerNameValid = regEx.IsMatch(containerName);
```

Source: Azure Portal --> New Container creation screen --> View Source :)

Comment: +1 for ingenuity, but I needed it in C sharp, sorry i should have tagged that

Comment: Updated my answer. `isContainerNameValid` will return true or false based on pattern matching.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of the Azure Storage Library now contains this method:

```
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.NameValidator.ValidateContainerName(myContainerName);
```

If the name is not valid it will throw an ArgumentException.

Better than trying to make your own.

Comment: Still not in the JavaScript version of the API :(